# How can I convert multiple HEX values into HSV values at once?

Tags: python

I'm using Python to convert colour HEX values into HSV values using the hex2rgb() and rgb2hsv() functions. More info about the code I'm using can be found here: https://codeigo.com/python/convert-hex-to-rgb-and-hsv.

The code works fine for 1 HEX value, but I cannot figure out how you can use this code for multiple HEX values.

**Example:** print(rgb2hsv(*hex2rgb("#b4a795"))) works and gives me the following output: (35, 17, 71). This is what I need, but how can you use this code if you have a list of multiple HEX values? Let's say HEX values #b4a795, #e7e0d6, #d7cfc8 as an example.

I have to add that I'm new to Python, so this might be a simple solution. In any case, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: using a for loop it may help

Answer (score 2):

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) could be helpful here. You can try something like:

```py
hex_values = ['#b4a795', '#e7e0d6', '#d7cfc8']

hsv_values = [rgb2hsv(*hex2rgb(hex_val)) for hex_val in hex_values]
```

Answer (score 0):

put your hex values in a list, then iterate it.

```
hexValues = ["#b4a795", "#e7e0d6", "#d7cfc8"]
hsvValues = []
for i in hexValues:
    hsvValues.append(rgb2hsv(*hex2rgb(i)))

print(hsvValues)
```

Comment: Hi Sembei, this worked as well, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your colours into a list and elaborate it with a for loop

```
def convert_series(color_list):
  my_list = []
  for x in range(0,len(color_list)):
    my_list.append(rgb2hsv(*hex2rgb(color_list[x])))
  return my_list

list_color = ['#b4a795', '#e7e0d6', '#d7cfc8']

print(convert_series(list_color))
new_list = convert_series(list_color)
```

You can then access to them via `new_list[0]`,`new_list[1]` etc

I suggest to check [Python documentation on for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) and [lists/data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for sharing your code, it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Paul96 feel free to accpet it if you feel it helped